# vue-btn doesn't submit on enter key

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this usual login form with submit button on the end, I have to click the button with mouse to submit the button. I want to submit the form with just enter key

this is my button code

```
<v-btn
 color="gray"
 padding="20"
 data-cy="button-login"
 @click="login"
 >
 SIGN IN
</v-btn>
```

this is my javascript login function

```
methods: {
 login () {
 let params = {
  mail: this.email,
  password: this.password
  }
   this.$store.dispatch('login', params).then((response) => {
   this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard', params: {'userId': String(response.data.user_id)}})
  }).catch(() => {
   this.submitsnackbar = true
  })
 }
}
```

It will help me a lot if I can just press enter to login
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your form and `<v-btn>` in a `<v-form>` component and then use the `@submit` event handler on the `<v-form>` to handle the form submission. Since you didn't specify the major version of Vuetify that you are using, here is the link to each of the `<v-form>` component definitions, depending on your framework version:

- 1.5.x => https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms
- 2.x.x => https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/

Comment: thank you very much for the answer I will look up to it

Answer (score 13):

Move `login` method call to `form` element and declare `v-btn` `type` as `submit`-

```
<v-form @submit="login">
 <v-btn
  color="gray"
  padding="20"
  data-cy="button-login"
  type="submit"
 >
  SIGN IN
 </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Comment: thank you very much, and sorry because I am really newbie at this

Comment: you can also use `@submit.prevent="login"` to only execute your `login` method without the default submit behaviour