# Jest: wrapper.find().simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter', keycode: 13}) is not function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

Continue from this question

[vue-btn doesn't submit on enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732539/vue-btn-doesnt-submit-on-enter-key)

I have this sign in page that can login using 'Enter' in keyboard
I want to do unit test when simulate enter key on keyboard, it can login automatically.

This is the test code that I have:

```
describe('Login.vue', () => {
    const vuetify = new Vuetify()
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        actions: {
            login: jest.fn()
        }
    })
    const wrapper = mount(Login, { stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view'], store, vuetify })

    it('login using enter key on keyboard', async () => {
        wrapper.setData({ email: 'user@example.com' })
        wrapper.setData({ password: 'Passw0rd' })
        
        await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
        wrapper.find('[data-cy="input-password"]').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter', keycode: 13})
    })
})
```

I already did the Integration Test using Cypress, but I want to do the unit test first before submitting it into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
await wrapper.find('#myFieldID').vm.$emit('keypress', {type: 'enter'});
```

So, in this case, the line should be:

```
wrapper.find('[data-cy="input-password"]').vm.$emit('keypress', {type: 'Enter'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [trigger event](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html#trigger) from [Vue Test Utils](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/):

```
wrapper.find('[data-cy="input-password"]').trigger('keyup.enter')
```

Comment: This answer is in the 'low quality answers queue"